# Plot data from two different select inputs

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I am new to Shiny and reactivity and doing my homework. I can't figure out how to solve the following problem. I would like to have a plot which by default shows all genders where x-axis is height and y-axis is homeworld (as it is now). Then I would like to have two multi select inputs from where I could choose conditions for my plot. For example, when I choose white Hair (or several other types) I should see only observations that I applied for Hair (similarly for Species). But when I choose brown Hair and human Species it should point me to the observations that meet both conditions. On default the plot should show all observations when on x-axis is height and y-axis is homeworld. Here is what I have done so far.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(plotly)

?starwars



# Step 1 - prepare row data

# a) add missing info

starwars_data = starwars %>%
  mutate(
    ID = rownames(starwars),
    height = case_when(
      name == 'Finn' ~ as.integer(178),
      name == 'Rey' ~ as.integer(170),
      name == 'Poe Dameron' ~ as.integer(172),
      name == 'BB8' ~ as.integer(67),
      name == 'Captain Phasma' ~ as.integer(200),
      TRUE ~ height
    ),
    mass = case_when(
      name == 'Finn' ~ 73,
      name == 'Rey' ~ 54,
      name == 'Poe Dameron' ~ 80,
      name == 'BB8' ~ 18,
      name == 'Captain Phasma' ~ 76,
      TRUE ~ mass
    ),
    film_counter = lengths(films),
    vehicle_counter = lengths(vehicles),
    starship_counter = lengths(starships)
  ) %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(replace(., is.na(.), 'not applicable')))


# 2) Prepare layout

hair = starwars_data %>% 
  select(hair_color) %>% 
  distinct()


spec = starwars_data %>% 
  select(species) %>% 
  distinct()


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput('hair', 'Hair', hair, multiple = TRUE),
      selectInput('spec', 'Species', spec, multiple = TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput('plot'),
      tableOutput('txt2')
      #dataTableOutput('table'))
    )
  )
)


srv <- function(input, output){


  starwars_data_hair = reactive({
    input$hair
    starwars_data %>%
      filter(hair_color %in% input$hair)
  })

  starwars_data_species = reactive({
    input$spec
    starwars_data %>%
      filter(species %in% input$spec)
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly((starwars_data),
            source = 'scatter') %>%
      add_markers(
        x = ~height,
        y = ~homeworld,
        color = ~factor(gender),
        key = ~ID
      ) %>%
      layout(
        xaxis = list(title = 'Height', rangemode = "tozero"),
        yaxis = list(title = 'Homeland', rangemode = "tozero"),
        dragmode = "select"
      )
  })

}
  shinyApp(ui, srv)
```

Thank you for any hints.

Comment: Your code isn't complete. Chk please!

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things:

- You are using the same input `starwars_data` dataframe for plotting hence the plot remains unchanged despite selection
- You don't need two different reactive functions for filtering
- Accessing reactive element is like accessing function hence I've used `starwars_data_filtered()` for plotting

Check the updated code:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(plotly)

?starwars



# Step 1 - prepare row data

# a) add missing info

starwars_data = starwars %>%
  mutate(
    ID = rownames(starwars),
    height = case_when(
      name == 'Finn' ~ as.integer(178),
      name == 'Rey' ~ as.integer(170),
      name == 'Poe Dameron' ~ as.integer(172),
      name == 'BB8' ~ as.integer(67),
      name == 'Captain Phasma' ~ as.integer(200),
      TRUE ~ height
    ),
    mass = case_when(
      name == 'Finn' ~ 73,
      name == 'Rey' ~ 54,
      name == 'Poe Dameron' ~ 80,
      name == 'BB8' ~ 18,
      name == 'Captain Phasma' ~ 76,
      TRUE ~ mass
    ),
    film_counter = lengths(films),
    vehicle_counter = lengths(vehicles),
    starship_counter = lengths(starships)
  ) %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(replace(., is.na(.), 'not applicable')))


# 2) Prepare layout

hair = starwars_data %>% 
  select(hair_color) %>% 
  distinct()


spec = starwars_data %>% 
  select(species) %>% 
  distinct()


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput('hair', 'Hair', hair, multiple = TRUE),
      selectInput('spec', 'Species', spec, multiple = TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput('plot'),
      tableOutput('txt2')
      #dataTableOutput('table'))
    )
  )
)


srv <- function(input, output){


  starwars_data_filtered = reactive({
    input$hair
    starwars_data %>%
      filter(hair_color %in% input$hair) %>% 
      filter(species %in% input$spec)
  })



  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
    plot_ly((starwars_data_filtered()),
            source = 'scatter') %>%
      add_markers(
        x = ~height,
        y = ~homeworld,
        color = ~factor(gender),
        key = ~ID
      ) %>%
      layout(
        xaxis = list(title = 'Height', rangemode = "tozero"),
        yaxis = list(title = 'Homeland', rangemode = "tozero"),
        dragmode = "select"
      )
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, srv)
```

Comment: Okay, I understand that part. But what If I decide to filter only for "Hair" and leave "Species" blank (and the other way round)?

Answer (score 0):

I think I am getting there, here is what I have done:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(DT)
library(plotly)

?starwars



# Step 1 - prepare row data

# a) replace NA values in columns

starwars_data_as_table <- as_tibble(starwars)
starwars_data_as_table$gender[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$gender)] <- 'not applicable'
starwars_data_as_table$homeworld[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$homeworld)] <- 'unknown'
starwars_data_as_table$species[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$species)] <- 'unknown'
starwars_data_as_table$hair_color[is.na(starwars_data_as_table$hair_color)] <- 'not applicable'

# b) add missing info

starwars_data = starwars_data_as_table %>%
  mutate(
    ID = rownames(starwars),
    height = case_when(
      name == 'Finn' ~ as.integer(178),
      name == 'Rey' ~ as.integer(170),
      name == 'Poe Dameron' ~ as.integer(172),
      name == 'BB8' ~ as.integer(67),
      name == 'Captain Phasma' ~ as.integer(200),
      TRUE ~ height
    ),
    mass = case_when(
      name == 'Finn' ~ 73,
      name == 'Rey' ~ 54,
      name == 'Poe Dameron' ~ 80,
      name == 'BB8' ~ 18,
      name == 'Captain Phasma' ~ 76,
      TRUE ~ mass
    ),
    film_counter = lengths(films),
    vehicle_counter = lengths(vehicles),
    starship_counter = lengths(starships)
  )

typeof(starwars_data)


# 2) Prepare layout

hair = starwars_data %>%
  select(hair_color) %>%
  arrange(hair_color) %>% 
  distinct()


spec = starwars_data %>% 
  select(species) %>% 
  arrange(species) %>% 
  distinct()


ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput('hair', 'Hair', hair, multiple = TRUE),
      selectInput('spec', 'Species', spec, multiple = TRUE)
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotlyOutput('plot')
      # tableOutput('txt2')
      #dataTableOutput('table'))
    )
  )
)


srv <- function(input, output){

  d = starwars_data

  starwars_data_filtered <-  reactive({

    if(length(input$hair) > 0){
      d <-  d %>% 
        filter(hair_color %in% input$hair)
    }
    if (length(input$spec) > 0) {
      d <-  d %>% 
        filter(species %in% input$spec)
    } 
    if (length(input$spec) > 0 & length(input$hair) > 0) {
        d <-  d %>% 
          filter(hair_color %in% input$hair) %>% 
            filter(species %in% input$spec)
    }
    d
  })


  output$plot <- renderPlotly({
      plot_ly(starwars_data_filtered(),
              source = 'scatter') %>%
        add_markers(
          x = ~height,
          y = ~homeworld,
          color = ~factor(gender),
          key = ~ID
        ) %>%
        layout(
          xaxis = list(title = 'Height', rangemode = "tozero"),
          yaxis = list(title = 'Homeland', rangemode = "tozero"),
          dragmode = "select"
        )
  })

}
shinyApp(ui, srv)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and little advise on how to post here.

Comment: Another added info, You've got to upvote the answers that helped you and mark the answer right that solved your problem. This is to help anyone coming to your question in future.